# No errors, but output is not right. Pointer issue possibly

Tags: c++, class, file-io

Im reading strings from a file and inserting them into a LinkedList in alphabetical order (C++). I have made the node and list classes but something is wrong with them. I have done this in Java and it works 100% without any problems. This leads me to believe that I must have messed up with pointers somewhere. This is also only the second time I use the '->' symbol. So I may have used it erroneously somewhere. Some helpful tips are appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
//NODE CLASS
#include <string>
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std;

class Node {
    string word;
    int count;
    Node* next;

    public:
    Node (string aWord) {
        word = aWord;
        count = 1;
    }

    Node (string aWord, Node* theNext) {
        word = aWord;
        next = theNext;
    }

    void increaseCount() {
        count++;
    }

    string getWord() {
        return word;
    }

    int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    Node* getNext() {
        return next;
    }

    void setNext(Node* theNext) {
        next = theNext;
    }
};

//LIST CLASS
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class LinkedList {
    Node* head;

    public:
    LinkedList() {
        head = new Node(" ");
    }

    void insert(string word) {
        Node* temp = head;
        Node* previous = head;

    while (temp != NULL && temp->getWord() < word) {
        previous = temp;
        temp = temp->getNext();
    }

    if (temp == NULL) {
        Node* node= new Node(word);
        previous-> setNext(node);
    } else {
        if (temp-> getWord() == word) {
            temp->increaseCount();
        } else if (temp->getWord() > word) {
            Node* node = new Node(word, temp);
            previous->setNext(node);
        }
      }
    }

    void print() {
        Node* temp = head->getNext();
        while (temp != NULL) {
            cout<< temp;
            temp=temp->getNext();
        }
    }
};

//MAIN
#include <iostream>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "Node.h"
#include "LinkedList.h"
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

        ifstream inFile("WordsStatisticData1.txt");

        if (!inFile.is_open())
        cout<< "Could not open the file"<< endl;

        else {
            string readData;
            LinkedList list = *new LinkedList(); //Probably a problem here

            while (inFile >> readData) {
                list.insert(readData);
                inFile.close();

                list.print();
            }
        }
    }
```

I may be declaring things totally wrong within the main as well.
My output looks like an address '0x' with random characters.

Comment: `LinkedList list = *new LinkedList();` is a memory leak. How do you free it? In fact, I don't think you need a pointer here at all.

Comment: True. An error on my part. No allocation needed for this part

Comment: @DSib13 - `I have done this in Java and it works 100% without any problems`  Because Java does all of the dynamic memory management for you in the form of garbage collection.  As a matter of fact, your code leaks memory all over the place due to no calls to `delete`, something you don't worry about in Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're printing out `temp` where `temp` is a `Node*`. A pointer is just the address of an object, hence why you're getting an address in your output.

Seems like you want to get the string that the `Node` contains. If so, you want:

```
cout << temp->getWord();
```

Another problem you have is that you close your file and print the list inside the loop, which means it'll happen right after the first word has been read. You probably mean to do this *after* the loop, so all of the words in the file can be read.

You also have problem with the line you marked as such. Using the `new` keyword will dynamically allocate an object. These objects need to be later deleted with `delete`. However, you dereference the dynamically allocated object (with `*`) and copy it, losing any reference to the dynamically allocated object - this is a classic memory leak. The dynamic allocation here is completely unnecessary. Just do:

```
LinkedList list;
```

Comment: Right. That did remove the address, but it outputted only the very first word in the file.

Comment: @DSib13 There are other problems. Did you meant to close the file and print the list *after* the loop?

Comment: I actually had my list defined in that manner but XCode quipped back with a suggestion so I took it and never switched it back.My output is correct for the most part, thank you. But duplicate words are appearing when they should only appear once followed by the number of times they appear

Comment: Got it. Thank you so much for your help. Sometimes, one needs a second pair of eyes. Or better practice. Thanks again